# CSS : modifying the style of a div if it his parent has a specific class

Tags: css

I've am stuck on this css issue. Here is a simplified code :

```
<div class="parent type1">
     <div class="child">
          red
     </div>
</div>
<div class="parent type2">
     <div class="child">
          blue
     </div>
<div>
```

I don't know how to code this (or if I can code this) but I need something like :
"If class is "child" and parent's class is "type2", put the div in blue (without changing the red div)".

Knowing that in my specific situation, I can't change the html, so I can't add some ids.

Thank you in advance and have a great day ! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Chained CSS could do the trick:

```
.type2 .child {
  color: blue;
}

/* OR combined classes + child */
.parent.type2 .child {
  color: blue;
}

/* OR direct child of type2 */
.type2 > .child {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Look here for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: thank you very much ! The second solution was very helpful :-)

Comment: You're welcome :) feel free to mark this as a solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.type2 div{
color : blue;
}

.type2 .child{
 color : blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent type1">
     <div class="child">
          red
     </div>
</div>
<div class="parent type2">
     <div class="child">
          blue
     </div>
<div>
```